# Combine fuzzing with tracing of execution path

Tags: c++, c, clang, llvm, fuzzing

I want to trace execution paths for a program for multiple inputs. To generate inputs I currently use coverage-guided fuzzing - I first tried [AFL](https://github.com/google/AFL) and now use [Libfuzzer](https://llvm.org/docs/LibFuzzer.html). To record execution paths I looked at [XRay](https://llvm.org/docs/XRay.html) and [SanitizerCoverage](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SanitizerCoverage.html) which both leverage LLVM instrumentation as far as I understood; the latter is used internally by Libfuzzer for its coverage metrics.

If I use XRay with Libfuzzer, I receive error messages because of multiple function definitions:

```
#include <xray/xray_log_interface.h>

extern "C" {
    int LLVMFuzzerRunDriver(int *argc, char ***argv, int (*UserCb)(const uint8_t *Data, size_t Size));
};

extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *data, size_t size)
{
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return LLVMFuzzerRunDriver(&argc, &argv, &LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput);
}
```

```sh
clang++-13 -o test test.cpp -fxray-instrument -fxray-instruction-threshold=1 -fsanitize=fuzzer-no-link -L /usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/lib/linux/ -l clang_rt.fuzzer_no_main-x86_64
```

If I use Libfuzzer with the SanitizerCoverage callback:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <sanitizer/coverage_interface.h>

extern "C" void __sanitizer_cov_trace_pc_guard(uint32_t *guard) {
  if (!*guard) return;
  return;
}

extern "C" {
    int LLVMFuzzerRunDriver(int *argc, char ***argv, int (*UserCb)(const uint8_t *Data, size_t Size));
};

extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *data, size_t size)
{
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return LLVMFuzzerRunDriver(&argc, &argv, &LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput);
}
```

```sh
$ clang++-13 -o test2 test2.cpp -fsanitize=fuzzer-no-link -fsanitize-coverage=trace-pc-guard -L /usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/lib/linux/ -l clang_rt.fuzzer_no_main-x86_64

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/lib/linux//libclang_rt.fuzzer_no_main-x86_64.a(fuzzer_no_main.o): in function `__sanitizer_cov_trace_pc_guard':
(.text.__sanitizer_cov_trace_pc_guard+0x0): multiple definition of `__sanitizer_cov_trace_pc_guard'; /tmp/test2-047590.o:test2.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

Is it possible to combine out-of-the-box fuzzing (for generating 'interesting' inputs) and execution path tracing or do I have to resort to something more demanding like [writing my own LLVM pass](https://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your goal. With AFL you can check all the edges it hits with afl-showmap and use afl-cov to get a gcov result. is this something you want?

Comment: As far as I understood the afl coverage results, I do not get individual traces for inputs, i.e. I know that the functions foo(), bar() and baz() are covered during a run, but I do not know in which order the functions were executed by which input

Comment: ah fair enough - that sounds expensive in terms of performance. You may want to read a bit into AFLGo, which computes function distance to a target before a fuzzing campaign.